# Нажатие двух, трех итд кнопок одновременно в Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, gui, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет! Гугл информации не дал, вопрос следующий:
Есть код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe")
w.get("http://mysite.com/")
element0 = w.find_element_by_link_text('Done')
element0.click()
```

Вопрос следующий: из-за всплывающей анимации на сайте я вынужден ждать, пока она завершится и только потом нажимать вторую кнопку. Можно ли как-то в Selenium нажать две (или более) кнопок одновременно? было бы очень удобно. Спасибо!

Comment: а пользователь по вашему мнению должен тоже 2 раза моментально нажать lдолжен??

Comment: у пользователя будет две мышки))))))))))) ну если серьёзно, можно попробовать один элемент выделить TAB'ом, а второй мышкой, и постараться одновременно нажать ENTER и ЛКМ ))))

Comment: Анимация у вас какая? Ну то есть это элемент сайта или баннер или ещё какая приблуда? Может проще прекратить анимацию (закрыть, скрыть)?

Comment: анимация всплывающий алерт, конечно как вариант запретить их, но идеально было бы нажать несколько кнопок и не заморачиваться

Comment: просто представьте, как бы вы это сделали обычной мышкой. Ок. Как бы поступить браузеру, если пользователь нажал две кнопки с двумя разными url?

Comment: Вам или явное ожидание нужно сделать на элементы анимации, или нажать на крестик анимации, или скрыть анимацию изменив CSS свойство